# Unknown column in mySQL CSV import

Tags: django, mysql, django-models

I am trying to import a small CSV file into my django program.  I am using SQL, and here is what I have so far.  The CSV file itself has Column1 which is named Customer and I am trying to take that information and assign it to the model field name 'client_name'.  Problem I get when I run this query is that I keep getting the unknown column 'customer' in field list error, but not sure how to fix it.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'home/steve/Desktop/ClientListing_2.csv' INTO TABLE clients_clients
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
SET Customer = client_name;
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I don't think that's the correct syntax at all.  MySQ's LOAD DATA has no syntax for associating a column label with a column; it's basically all positional.  Have you considered writing a simple django management command to import the CSV file?

Comment: @Elf as of right now, all I need is to import this file once, then we will use this system from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I keep an empty (i.e. terminated with a "pass") management around it a zip file that I can unravel whenever I need a one-off.  If you're struggling with MySQL, do it The Django Way:

```
from django.core.management import BaseCommand
import csv
from clients.models import Client
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self,*args,**options):
        for row in csv.reader(open('path/to/ClientListing_2.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"'):
            if row[0] == 'Customer': 
                continue
            Client.objects.get_or_create(client_name = row[0])
```

Save it, run it, delete it.  This method guarantees that Django IDs are generated correctly.  There are smarter ways to do this (guaranteeing uniqueness would be a good idea!), but this is the core idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing a little bit here, but it sounds like you have a CSV with a header row, and you want to load the first column of that CSV into the client_name column of a table names clients_clients.

Is that right?

If so, this should work:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'home/steve/Desktop/ClientListing_2.csv' 
INTO TABLE clients_clients 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(client_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you might be trying to load columns in a different order and perhaps just a subset of the columns. If so, the correct syntax is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'home/steve/Desktop/ClientListing_2.csv'
INTO TABLE clients_clients
(client_name, ...)
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

In other words, use a column list to fill just some of the columns or to change the order from your csv file.

Comment: Seen [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html) you can see that the field list can only occur after the FIELDS/LINES TERMINATED BY... and whatever field isn't included will be wiped out. Alternatively you can include all fields and not make the list of them. Great answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12329794/469643.