# mysql LOAD DATA INFILE update

Tags: mysql

I am currently using mySQL LOAD DATA INFILE to insert a csv file into my database. This csv file is downloaded to the server on a daily basis in order to keep product data up-to-date.

What I want to know is how can I update the table with the new csv and preserve the existing data where it's not different?

Here is my current statement:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file' REPLACE INTO TABLE products FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\\' IGNORE 1 LINES (aw_product_id,merchant_id,merchant_image_url,aw_deep_link,description,in_stock,merchant_name,brand_name,display_price,product_name,rrp_price,merchant_category
```

This works fine but it replaces the ID column with a completely new set and also reverts columns that I want to ignore, back to the default state. For example I have a column called 'Published' with a value of 0 or 1. If I use REPLACE it sets that column back to 0.

How can I use REPLACE but ignore some columns?

Answer (score 7):

The answer to *How can I use REPLACE but ignore some columns?* is **you can't**: `REPLACE` allways replaces a complete row, not the single field values of that row.

The answer to *Can I still achieve my goal* though is **Yes**: My recommendation would be to `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` into another table, then use a stored procedure or query to `INSERT` and `UPDATE` (as opposed to `REPLACE`) your main table. If you give us a bit more information (table structure, which column matches the loaded data with the existing data) we might be able to help you further.

Comment: @Eugen Rieck :  Is there any other way to do it directly with LOAD DATA feature  ? I searched lot but unable to find solution.

Answer (score 3):

**If augmenting/changing the table:**

First `LOAD DATA` into a tmp_table.
Then use this to either create a new row or update an existing row:

```
INSERT INTO real_table
    SELECT ... FROM tmp_table
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        a = VALUES(a), ...
```

If this table is quite big, consider "chunking" those IODKUs.  See [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) for chunking tips.

Note: IODKU requires a `UNIQUE` (possibly `PRIMARY`) `KEY` to control which row to `UPDATE`.

**If replacing the *entire* table**, then this is much better:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
LOAD DATA ... INTO new;
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real; -- atomic and fast (no downtime)
DROP TABLE old;
```

**Replace**

Do not use `REPLACE`; it is a `DELETE` plus an `INSERT`.  If you have `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then those ids are thrown away ("burned"), and you could run out of ids after a few months.

Comment: Hello friends, I have a table with 7 columns, the primary key does not work for me very much for this query, since it is based on columns and values, I want to insert or update a single column from a csv file; The problem is that Duplicate is not used correctly, and if possible for this scenario: if in a row three of the columns A, B, C match their values (already exists a record) do the update; If there is no match make an insert in the queue.